# JPA @GenerateValue not generating values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jpa

I'm setting up a table/entity to auto-generate int values in the first column of a table which will most likely just be the primary key for now in Eclipse with MySQL. It looks like I have it set up correctly
with:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Table")
public class Table implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private int id;
```

It's connecting to the database fine and actually persisting values to the non ID part. The problem is that it's not generating anything for the id. The mysql has a default value of '0' that it's placing in the id column. I'm not getting any errors it just fills the column with '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a generation type of IDENTITY you tell JPA the database will do the id generation. So you will have to setup the column to use AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: That was it. I thought that JPA would some how "handle" this since I indicated my intent through annotation. But the mySQL AUT_INCREMENT works fine.